# TCP syn, ack Lost Before Entering IPsec VPN tunnel

Tags: vpn, ipsec, syn

I have configured a site to site VPN which is working fine as traffic is going through the tunnel. I am able to ping and Telnet hosts on the other network and they are able to ping me back.

The problem I have is that when hosts on the other network send HTTP requests to an app on the web server (This is actually an app for delivering USSD menus back to the mobile subscriber, The other hosts are servers from the Mobile Network Provider), I can the requests and a hand shake is started with a SYN from the other hosts! My server replies with a SYN, ACK but to everyones suprise, those responses are not arriving on the other side. I am using a Cisco 820 as the router and VPN Server. Inspection on the router configuration do not show anything out of the ordinary anyway, from as far as I can tell. I do not have any firewall enabled and I am using access-lists for routing and access control.

What I suspect is that the packets are being dropped by the router before they can get encrypted and sent on the Ipsec Tunnel. Please someone advise what could be dropping these packets.

No further communication is done because the three-way handshake fails.

This the packet trace:

```
    25.690224 200.32.15.154 -> 192.168.0.2  TCP 74 45367 > http [SYN]          Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=610983874 TSecr=0 WS=128
    25.690267  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763845089 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    26.687067  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763845339 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    28.687066  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763845839 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    31.688116 200.32.15.154 -> 192.168.0.2  TCP 74 45367 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=610989874 TSecr=0 WS=128
    31.688147  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763846589 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    32.687068  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763846839 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    40.687059  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763848839 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    43.689503 200.32.15.154 -> 192.168.0.2  TCP 74 45367 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=5840 Len=0 MSS=1452 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=611001874 TSecr=0 WS=128
    43.689531  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763849589 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
    56.887060  192.168.0.2 -> 200.32.15.154 TCP 74 http > 45367 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=14480 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=763852889 TSecr=610983874 WS=128
```

This is my Iptables on the server:

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    fail2ban-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  anywhere                     anywhere             multiport dports pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps
    fail2ban-pureftpd  tcp  --  anywhere                     anywhere             multiport dports ftp
    fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport         dports ssh
    fail2ban-dovecot-pop3imap  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports pop3,pop3s,imap2,imaps
    fail2ban-pureftpd  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ftp
    fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh

    Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination

    Chain fail2ban-dovecot-pop3imap (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain fail2ban-pureftpd (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

    Chain fail2ban-ssh (2 references)
    target     prot opt source               destination
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
    RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

This is the access list pointing tot he internet and how i have programmed these addresses:

```
        150 deny ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 host 200.32.15.152 log (306 matches)
160 deny ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 host 200.32.15.153 log (101 matches)
170 deny ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 host 200.32.15.154 log (141 matches)
180 deny ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 host 200.32.15.155 log (74 matches)
```

This is the access list pointing tot he VPN:

```
        60 permit ip host 192.168.0.2 host 200.32.15.152 (132 matches)
70 permit ip host 192.168.0.2 host 200.32.15.153 (74 matches)
80 permit ip host 192.168.0.2 host 200.32.15.154 (146 matches)
90 permit ip host 192.168.0.2 host 200.32.15.155 (72 matches)
```

These are the SAs for those addresses:

```
    local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.0.2/255.255.255.255/0/0)
    remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (200.32.15.154/255.255.255.255/0/0)
    current_peer 41.72.111.122 port 500
 PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
#pkts encaps: 28, #pkts encrypt: 28, #pkts digest: 28
#pkts decaps: 68, #pkts decrypt: 68, #pkts verify: 68
#pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
#pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
#pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
#send errors 0, #recv errors 0

 local crypto endpt.: 41.222.240.23, remote crypto endpt.: 41.72.111.122
 path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb FastEthernet4.1
 current outbound spi: 0x8FD440DA(2413052122)
 PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

 inbound esp sas:
  spi: 0xD6FEA63C(3607012924)
    transform: esp-3des esp-sha-hmac ,
    in use settings ={Tunnel, }
    conn id: 19, flow_id: Onboard VPN:19, sibling_flags 80000040, crypto map: sshlink-to-savannah
    sa timing: remaining key lifetime (k/sec): (4263446/2717)
    IV size: 8 bytes
    replay detection support: Y
    Status: ACTIVE(ACTIVE)

 inbound ah sas:

 inbound pcp sas:

 outbound esp sas:
  spi: 0x8FD440DA(2413052122)
    transform: esp-3des esp-sha-hmac ,
    in use settings ={Tunnel, }
    conn id: 20, flow_id: Onboard VPN:20, sibling_flags 80000040, crypto map: sshlink-to-savannah
    sa timing: remaining key lifetime (k/sec): (4263446/2717)
    IV size: 8 bytes
    replay detection support: Y
    Status: ACTIVE(ACTIVE)

 outbound ah sas:

 outbound pcp sas:
```

Please somebody help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution, I had to include my public peer IP to the ACLs. Due to the natting, the return leg  of the handshake was being sent using the public peer IP, hence after adding the public peer IP to the ACLs, PRESTO!!! Everything worked.